# SSIS Conditionally process files in folder

Tags: file, loops, ssis

I'm looking to dynamically pass a file name to For Each File loop.  The outer loop will pass a number string to inner file loop and only process files that match expression

I added an outer loop that passes file number variable to inner loop.  I'm getting file not found when I debug.  In debug mode the

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t9N78.png)

The Company Id File loop passes a number to For Each file in folder variable.
Here's setup.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K2myM.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vudJB.png)

Comment: In your for each loop file container for the file name you can use a partial file name for what to look for so "*_abcd.pgp"  should get all files with abcd.pgp at the end of the name.  If you need to search for multiple patterhsn you can put another for each loop outside the file one, loop through the list of file name formats, then use each one in a variable and use the variable in the file task pattern.

Comment: I think I know what you mean. I will need an add a For Loop Container around the For each file container and pass the pattern in .  for example outer loop needs to run twice and pass in 1234 then 5678.

Comment: Ok, I can type it out in more detail if you need, or if you have specific question about a step let me know.